# iBooks Author widgets on portrait mode

Tags: ipad, ibooks

I am having problems on a book I am writing on iBooks Author using the Contemporary template. I did add an Image Gallery widget in landscape orientation, but it doesn't appear on portrait orientation.

Anyone knows what happens on portrait that it doesn't show the widget?

Comment: Looks like it happens on all templates...

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can only view the Gallery Widget in portrait mode if it is on a "page" not a "chapter" or "section" screen. It behaves differently though, it shows up smaller then goes fullscreen when you click on it.

Comment: But I cannot add Pages to the template on protrait... Can I??

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same problem and I think that if the gallery widget is anchored to text, then it shows up in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that widgets show only in the thumbnail track in Portrait mode. If, like me, you have hidden the thumbnail track (because you dont want to waste the real estate) you don't see the widget in Portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all widgets do not show up in portrait mode if you have them set to floating, check for that first.